# How to quickly recognise redundant flow control blocks?

Tags: if-statement

I've noticed a fluency in much older devs that they can look at an if-else block and quickly see a more concise way to structure the logic.

Apart from truth tables and experience, are there any techniques to become proficient in this?

Comment: Well, ReSharper will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Gain a good understanding of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Another point to remember is that having a single return point from a function is somewhat overrated - not adhering to that can simplify your logic significantly.

Apart from that... experience... reading other peoples code.